# SQL Server: getting error 26 after clicking on connect button

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have prepared a program with Visual Studio 2010 and I'm working with SQL Server 2008. Before 2 weeks ago, this connection was working properly. Now, I'm trying to use it again. When I'm clicking on the `Connect` button, it waits, and then gives this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   is not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server name is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified.)

I googled this issue, but nothing helps.

I will be grateful to help me with this issue.

Comment: What has changes in those two weeks? Did you install a new version of SQL Server on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Do  ensure that service is running. You can check this by writing this query on the query analyser as:-

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysprocesses WHERE LEFT(program_name, 8) = 'SQLAgent')
  PRINT 'Running!'
ELSE
  PRINT 'Not running';
```

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx):-

> - Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
> - Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such an    instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application
>     converts \    to . If you are not sure about your application, please
>     try both    Server\Instance and Server\Instance in your connection
>     string]
> - Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve    correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
> - Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server. If firewall    is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 1) I didn't change my servername, is: .\sqlexpress 2+3+4) How am i doing that?

Comment: @Nizan:- Did you checked that the service is running?

Comment: Sorry, i'm a beginner in SqlServer. till now i didn't face with this issue. So, i don't know how to check that.

Comment: You may try this to check if service is running:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250480(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: I'm so confuse, i'm trying to do that: On the Start menu, point to Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server (if you installed SQL Server 2000) or Microsoft SQL Server 7.0 (if you installed SQL Server 7.0), and then click Service Manager.  i dont find both: Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft SQL Server 7.0

Comment: Ok, Dont get confused try this Go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services. Now when the services get opened search for SQL SERVER services and check if it is running!

Comment: @Nizan:- Updated the query which can help you finding of Agent is running or not! Hope that helps!

Comment: OK. i will check that.

Comment: @Nizan:- DO let me know if that worked for you. P.S. If that will work dont forget to accept this as an answer!

Comment: Hi, i try that: Control Panel > Remove/install program>                  I found Microsoft Sql Server instead of Sql Server. I s it right? It's means that  Sql Sever service is running?

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and execute this code:
For default instance : NET START MSSQLSERVER 
For named instance : NET START MSSQL$